# positive definite of a matrix(diagonal decay)

Tags: linear-algebra

Is this matrix positive definite:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b &c & d\\b & b & c & d\\c & c & c & d\\d&d&d&d\end{bmatrix}$$

when $a>b>c>d>0$?

I tried several $a,b,c,d$, the result seems to be true, but I cannot prove it. Thanks!

Comment: See [Sylvester's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem may be even better.

Comment: Hi @JackD'Aurizio, thanks for your insightful comment! Could you please elaborate a little bit about why you want to use this theorem? Is it a tool to bound the eigenvalues of the above matrix? What it the projection matrix $P$ in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Sylvester's criterium $A$ is positive definite if all main determinants are positive. They are $D_1=a>0$, $D_2=b(a-b)>0$, $D_3=c(a-b)(b-c)>0$ and $D_4=d(a - b)(b - c)(c - d)>0$. Hence the matrix is positive definite.

Comment: BTW, how did you find the determinant(so quickly)? from the above row/column operation to upper/lower triangular matrix? Thanks!

Comment: The $1\times 1$ and $2\times 2$ determinants are easy; for the $3\times 3$ I used the [Sarrus rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus). The last one I have guessed :)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Friedrich Philipp and @Omnomnomnom's comments, I notice huge defects in my original proof. Instead, I would like to present an another
proof followed by @Omnomnomnom's method.

Denote the given matrix by $A$. Observe that
\begin{align}
A=\begin{bmatrix}a & b &c & d\\b & b & c & d\\c & c & c & d\\d&d&d&d\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix}a-b & 0 &0 &0 \\0 &  0& 0 &0 \\ 0& 0 & 0 & 0\\0& 0& 0&0\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}b-c & b-c &0 &0 \\b-c &  b-c& 0 &0 \\ 0& 0 & 0 & 0\\0& 0& 0&0\end{bmatrix}\\
&+
\begin{bmatrix}c-d & c-d &c-d &0 \\c-d &  c-d& c-d &0 \\ c-d& c-d & c-d & 0\\0& 0& 0&0\end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix}d & d &d &d\\d&  d& d &d \\ d& d & d & d\\d& d& d&d\end{bmatrix}\\
&=A_1+A_2+A_3+A_4,
\end{align}
where $A_i$ denotes the above corresponding decomposed matrix. Then given
$x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in{\sf R}^4$, we see that
\begin{align}
x^tAx&=x^tA_1x+x^tA_2x+x^tA_3x+x^tA_4x\\
     &=(a-b)x_1^2+(b-c)(x_1+x_2)^2+(c-d)(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2+d(x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4)^2.
\end{align}
That is, $x^tAx$ is the sum of the four non-zero terms. Now, if $x\neq{\it 0}$, we discuss the following cases.

1. $x_1\neq 0$: It is clear that
   $x^tAx\geq(a-b)x_1^2>0$.
2. $x_1=0$ and $x_2\neq 0$: It follows that $x^tAx\geq(b-c)x_2^2>0$.
3. $x_1=x_2=0$ and $x_3\neq 0$: It follows that $x^tAx\geq(c-d)x_3^2>0$.
4. $x_1=x_2=x_3=0$ and $x_4\neq 0$: It follows that $x^tAx= dx_4^2>0$.

Hence we conclude that $x^tAx>0$ for all $x\neq{\it 0}$, that is, $A$ is positive definite.

Comment: Thanks. This solves the problem(and can help find the determinant).

Comment: Elementary column operations don't help finding eigenvalues.

Comment: Column reduction does not generally give you the eigenvalues directly.  How did you deduce that the eigenvalues of the original matrix are positive?

Comment: Row-reduction (and column reduction) do *not* preserve the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Seems true. It preserves determinant and similarity(but not char. poly.), right?

Comment: If it "preserved similarity", then also the char.polynomial. So, no.

Comment: OK, so then only preserve determinant(product of eigenvalues). Does it preserve the sign of eigenvalues? Seems I need to check my linear algebra textbook once more...

Answer (score 1):

Note that this matrix is definitely positive *semidefinite*, since it is the sum of positive semidefinite matrices.  In particular, we can write
$$
A = (a-b)A_1 + (b-c)A_2 + (c-d)A_3 + dA_4
$$
Where the $A_i$ are rank 1 matrices that I claim are "obviously positive semidefinite".  To show that it's invertible, row-reduce.

Comment: I'd say this decomposition is not really obvious.

Comment: Thanks! This decomposition is interesting and I think it may help for further analysis the properties of this matrix.

Comment: @FriedrichPhillip it's not that the decomposition is obvious, but once it's pointed out, I think the implication is clear.